# Dedicated server has a range of IPs. Is there any benefit to having more than 1?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

I'm using a very powerful dedicated server :-D and it's got a whole range of external IPs.

I've got my DNS (cloudflare) pointing to the first, primary IP. But I can access the server from any of the IPs in the range.

Is there any benefit to setting up additional A records for my domain to point to the other IPs, or actually is there any detriment to this?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important use of multiple IP addresses per physical machine today (in my view) is the ability to create virtual machines on the host with its own IP addresses, but there might be other benefits as well, like if you can't use SNI for HTTPS and still want to use more than one vhost on the machine.

Comment: So are you saying with only 1 IP address, I couldn't host more than 1 website? I'm certain I can define several vhost configs, and have the DNS point all domains at the 1 IP, then the vhost configs would handle which directory/website is served up based on the domain the incoming request is coming from?

Comment: Yes, but that's not working with HTTPS without [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

Comment: @SvW To be more precise you can't have multiple https sites using **different certificates** on a single IP without requiring SNI (Server Name Indication). Multiple sites with a single wildcard cert or a SAN (Subject Alternative Name) cert which matches all of the site names would also work on a single IP.